# Should a transaction be at WCF service level or at Database access level?

Tags: c#, database, wcf, transactions, ado.net

So I understand that you can have transactions created automatically by WCF by using attributes on the operations like this:

```
[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true, TransactionAutoComplete = true)]
```

And on the interface like this:

```
[TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Mandatory)]
```

I also know that a transaction can be created using ADO.Net when reading from the database so my question is which is the best option?  At WCF level or database level?  Or does it depend on the specific scenario?

Comment: does it depend on the specific scenario - yes sir it does.Depends upon what are you trying to gaurentee with the transaction, if its just data integrity, then ADO.net is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ADO.NET ([local](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k2hy99x(v=vs.110).aspx)) transaction is tied directly to the database connection ([SqlConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx)), which means that you have to keep passing the connection around and it does not allow for cross database work. This is your fastest option.

The WCF way would allow you to have ambient transactions. Along with the attributes you noted, you will also need a [TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx). One advantage of TransactionScope, is that it isn't tied just to databases. Any transaction aware provider can use it. Additionally, it can handle a transaction that spans multiple connections. MSDTC comes into play if you need to work with multiple data sources. MSDTC implements a two phase commit protocol. A distributed transaction is slower than a local transaction.

So the answer is - it really comes down to your requirements. However, if you are only dealing with CRUD operations on a single database, then ADO.NET transactions are sufficient.